# Why can't I use a Guid as a generic type constraint?

Tags: c#, generics, types, constraints

I have this generic method as follows and I want to limit T to be only of type Guid like so:

```
public static EntityFindApiResponse EntityFind<T>(
    Credential cred, EntitiesApiClient entitiesApiClient, string clrType, 
    string propertyName, T searchKey)
    where T: Guid
{
    // ...
}
```

The compiler tells me that

> 'System.Guid' is not a valid constraint. A type used as a constraint must be an interface, a non-sealed class or a type parameter.

So, why isn't this working?

Comment: It seems like you could just get rid of the type parameter and make the last parameter of EntityFindApiResponse be of type Guid; have you tried this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, it turns out that `Guid` is a `struct`. You cannot set a generic constraint to a `struct` because `struct`s cannot be derived from (meaning you can't inherit from a `struct`).

Further to that `where T: Guid` really reads "where T is of type `Guid` or a type that derives from `Guid`" and since nothing can derived form a `struct`, it's like saying "where T is of type Guid" which defeats the purpose of generics to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

`Guid` is a struct, which means it does not meet the requirements:

> A type used as a constraint must be an interface, a non-sealed class
>   or a type parameter.

Comment: It can also be `struct`, which allows for value types to be used as type parameters (although you cannot impose a constraint on a specific struct type).

Comment: Yes, you're right. But how does it apply to that question?

Comment: No, not to the question. To your list of allowed constraints.

Comment: I don't get it. This question is about *why can't I use a concrete struct type (`Guid`) as generic type constraint*. It's not about *what are the possible generic constraints*. Do you think I should mention all the other possible ways to constraint a generic type argument, `class`, `struct`, `new()`, too?

Comment: I'm not looking for an argument. I get what you're saying. It's just when I first read your answer it seemed like that was all that's available for type constraints. No offense.

Comment: @MarcelN. You can add a generic constraint that the type be any type of struct.  You cannot add, as a generic constraint, that the generic argument be a specific type where that specific type is a struct, which is what this answer is stating.